# How can I use Debug.Write with dynamic data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am doing some scripting of Adobe InDesign. Their COM implementation is really designed for VB, so it's not rigorous about reporting data types, occasionally necessitating the use of dynamics.

I'm trying to debug a chunk of code that looks like this:

```
foreach (dynamic pi in current.PageItems)
{
    if (pi is TextFrame)
    {
        var frame = pi as TextFrame;
        var str = frame.Contents.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

This gives me a RuntimeBinderException like this:

> Additional information: Cannot dynamically invoke method 'WriteLine'
>   because it has a Conditional attribute

I get that the problem is that with Conditional attributes, the version of the code that needs to handle the type the dynamic resolves to at runtime might have gotten compiled out, but I'm explicitly converting what I want to debug to a string, so I don't see why this is still happening. How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're being bitten by your use of `var` here, is my guess.

I'm assuming that `Contents` is `dynamic`.

Consider this example:

```
dynamic d = null;
var s = d.ToString();
```

`s` is `dynamic` not `string`.

You'll want to cast the object to `object` before calling `ToString`, or cast the result of `ToString` to a `string`.  The point is that at some point, somewhere, you need a cast to get out of the `dynamic` cycle.

This is how I'd solve it:

```
string str = ((object)frame.Contents).ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

or

```
string str = frame.Contents.ToString() as string;
Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons I always tell junior devs to explicitly declare their types until they understand the implication of an implicit declaration.

Comment: @MetroSmurf There's that, and also knowing when you should avoid it in general.  When dealing with `dynamic` it's particularly useful to avoid `var` as it's often not obvious as a reader whether a particular variable is `dynamic` or not, even for someone rather familiar with all underlying concepts.  This is one of those "don't make me think!" times.

Comment: I blame Resharper, which whines at you if you explicitly declare a type it thinks could be `var`.

Comment: var is actually fine in the top example. It just needs to be cast.

Comment: @TomDeloford I didn't say it won't work, merely that it's preferable to avoid it as it makes it much easier to make mistakes in this context without realizing what you're doing.  I specifically state in the answer that the solution is to use a cast.

Comment: Your answer starts: "You're being bitten by your use of var". This I thought needed clarification that you can still use var and solve this issue.

Comment: @TomDeloford It is *not* factually incorrect.  His use of `var` is the reason the issue is hard for him to see, and almost certainly the reason why he doesn't understand the problem.  Were he to not have used it here he almost certainly wouldn't have had this problem.  The reason that he's struggling is because he's using `var` here, so that *is* what is biting him.

Answer (score 8):

> but I'm explicitly converting what I want to debug to a string

That's not actually true.

```
var str = frame.Contents.ToString();
```

This line is still completely dynamic.

You need to explicitly declare it as a `string`.

Alternatively, you could static-ize earlier by explicitly declaring `frame` as `TextFrame`.

Comment: `Alternatively, you could static-ize earlier by explicitly declaring frame as TextFrame` He already is.  `Contents`, of `TextFrame`, is itself `dynamic`.  It's not just `dynamic` because he hasn't cast the container to it's actual type.

Answer (score 6):

No one has said it this way so I will.

Change

```
 var str = frame.Contents.ToString();
```

to

```
 string str = frame.Contents.ToString();
```